# How to efficiently reduce a Collection of items where all permutations of possible combinations have to be checked?

Tags: java, algorithm, reduction

Let's say you're given this interface:

```java
public interface Item {
    boolean canCombine(Item other);

    Item combine(Item other);
```

Two items can be combined and reduced into a single item if `Item.canCombine(other)` returns true.

Given a Collection of these items that can possible be combined, how would you efficiently reduce the Collection so that every item that can be combined is combined.   Edit: If two items are combined and one of any one of those items is combinable with another, then that composite can be combined with the other item.  (A & B are combinable and B & C are combinable, then AB is combinable with C).

My attempt at this is uses a queue and pops the first item and uses it as an accumulator.  Then I loop through the rest of them Collection and combine any matches with the accumulator and remove them.   Finally I put the accumulator on the end of the queue so it can be reduced further.
This is O(n^2) though or worse.   I suspect there's a more efficient solution.

```java
    static Collection<Item> reduce(Deque<Item> items) {
        Item accumulator;
        var noMatches = new ArrayList<Item>();
        while ((accumulator = items.pollFirst()) != null) {
            boolean matched = false;
            for (Iterator<Item> otherIterator = items.iterator(); otherIterator.hasNext(); ) {
                Item next = otherIterator.next();
                if (accumulator.canCombine(next)) {
                    accumulator = accumulator.combine(next);
                    otherIterator.remove();
                    matched = true;
                }
            }
            if (matched) {
                items.addLast(accumulator);
            } else {
                noMatches.add(accumulator);
            }
        }
        items.addAll(noMatches);
        return items;
    }
```

Comment: I think the worst case will be O(n^2) if `canCombine()` returns false always.

Comment: @MaruthiAdithya Nice observation.  Perhaps I can optimize for that case at least.

Comment: If you need to check each of *n* items against each of the other *n* - 1 items, then you can never do better than O( *n* ^2).

Comment: @marathon Suppose an item is combined with another, does it mean that it cant be combined with others? Example A can be combined with B and B with C. Does it mean A,B,C are combined or it will always be {A,B} and C?

Comment: @MaruthiAdithya A, B and C would all be combined into {A,B,C}.  If any one of the composite is combinable with another, the composite is combinable.  Thank you for helping me clarify the problem.

Comment: Is `canCombine` an equivalence relation? That is, reflexive, symmetric and transitive? Is there any property you can calculate for each Item separately that would allow bucketing into "maybe combinable" groups? (I'm implying an approach you could take if you have equals and hashCode-like properties).

Comment: @AndyTurner - yes, it is an equivalence relation.  The impl is based on whether there is an intersection of a set contained within Item.   `item1.someSet ∩ item2.someSet > 0`.  I suppose I could invert Item and have the set contents mapped to the items that hold them and merge that way.

Comment: @marathon Is this code working for all cases? I have a strong feeling that this might go into an infinite loop for a few cases - for instance, when no match is found. Also, there is no termination of the while loop.

Comment: If you can deduce the equivalence class from each item, then you can build a map from equivalence class to item and reduce time complexity to near O( *n* ).